# twitter Bootstrap Collapse menu not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working with the starter template found [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html) for Bootstrap. The css renders fine, but when the page is minimized, the collapsible menu does not work. IE, when I click the collapse button, nothing happens.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
      <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I modified css references and js reverences from original as file structure from bootstrap was different than template. I have left icon's alone for time being although the path is not valid.

Comment: posted the solution plz check and let us know . So that I can help you incase you get stuck .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include jquery in the footer before bootstrap javascripts files,  like below :

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also you dont have to use both min and main js file . remove bootstrap.js if you want to use minified version or remove bootstrap.min.js if you want to use the main version .

I will advise you to use bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Thank you much Shail. That did it. ended up copying the javascript over as server may not be connected to internet.

Comment: cool! let me know if ya get stuck anywhere in bootstrap .. I can polish and strap well ... hehe

Comment: Might take you up on that!